SQL PLus Outputting Query and Results when using spool
I have strange issue .  I am using the spool function to output the results of a query, however whenever I run the query both the query and results are spooled into the output file & Script Output window.
How can I stop the SQL Script from being spooled?
Could this be because I'm using variables in the Script to make changing them easier?  I am eventually appending three queries into one output file, so I would like to keep the variables.
Define OutputFile = '\\DIR\Filename.txt'
Define CompanyID = 31
Define ClientID = 40023382

SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET UNDERLINE OFF
SET COLSEP '|'
SET HEADING OFF
SET RECSEP OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0
--SET LINESIZE 1000
SET TRIMSPOOL OFF

SPOOL '&OutputFile' APPEND
--Column ID Format A15 --may not be needed as its integer
Column EFFDate Format A20
Column EventID Format A10
Column TransactionRef Format A10
Column ClientID Format A25
Column ClientName Format A100
Column Agent Format A30
Column Fund Format A17
Column Department Format A10
Column Product Format A10
Column LegalEntity Format A30
Column PmtRectNo Format A10
Column PayingInRef Format A50
Column TransactionDescription Format A25
Column TransCD Format A25
--Column MatchID Format 99999999999999999999999  --may not be needed as its integer
Column MatchDate Format A25
Column MatchStatus Format A25
Column Comments Format A25
Column Currency Format A10
Column Amount Format 999999999999999.9999
--Column DCIP Format A4 --may not be needed as its integer
Column BalancePool Format A50
Column Poolname Format A50



Select 
    trim(ITMH.ID) as ID,
    trim(To_CHAR(ITMH.EFFECTIVEDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) as EFFDate,
    trim(ITMH.REFNum) as EventID,
    Trim(itmh.Zip) as TransactionRef,
    trim(ITMH.UserText2) as ClientID,
    trim(ITMH.ImageURL) as ClientName,
    trim(ITMH.City) as Agent,
    trim(ITMH.CPCS) as Fund,
    Trim(ITMH.DepartmentID) as Department,
    trim(ITMH.ClerkID) as Product,
    trim(ITMH.Reason) as LegalEntity,
    trim(ITMH.PayeeNum) as PmtRectNo,
    trim(ITMH.USERTEXT39) as PayingInRef,
    trim(ITMH.Name1) as TransactionDescription, 
    Trim(ITMH.Branch) as TransCD,
    trim(ITMH.MatchID) as MatchID,
    'TBC' as MatchDate,
    'TBC' as MatchStatus,
    trim(ITMH.UserText1) as Comments,    
    trim(ITMH.CURRENCY) as Currency,
    ITMH.AMOUNT as Amount, -- Will never be null
    trim(ITMH.DCIP) as DCIP,
    trim(GRPC.Name) as BalancePool,
    trim(APOL.Name) as Poolname 
from 
    RECON.ITEMHISTORY ITMH
Join 
    RECON.AccountPool APOL
on
    ITMH.PoolID = APOL.ID
and ITMH.CompanyID = APOL.CompanyID
Join
    RECON.Class CLSS
on
    ITMH.Class = CLSS.ID
and ITMH.CompanyID = CLSS.CompanyID
Join 
    RECON.GROUPS GRP 
on 
    APOL.id = GRP.OWNERID
and APOL.CompanyID = GRP.CompanyID
Join 
    groupcategory GRPC 
on 
    GRP.MINORCAT = GRPC.ID
and GRP.CompanyID = GRPC.CompanyID
AND GRP.MAJORCAT = 1   
AND GRP.GROUPTYPE = 4098
Join 
    RECON.Account ACC
on
    ITMH.AccountID = ACC.ID
and ITMH.CompanyID = ACC.CompanyID
AND 
    GRP.MAJORCAT = 1
AND 
    GRP.GROUPTYPE = 4098
Where
    ITMH.CompanyID = &CompanyID
And
    ITMH.UserText2 = &ClientID
and 
    ABS(ITMH.ID) -- SEE NOTES
    in(
        Select ABS(ISC.ID) --  SEE NOTES
        from SCHEMA.MIG_F2K_ITEM_SNAPSHOT_&CompanyID ISC
        Where ISC.MIGRATED = 'N'
                )
--and ABS(ITMH.ID) = ABS(-21742607)  -- For debugging the rounding issue
--and ABS(ITMH.ID) -- SEE NOTES
--    in(
--        Select ABS(HAUD.ITEMID) --  SEE NOTES
--        from RECON.HISTORICALITEMAUDITTRAIL HAUD
--        Where HAUD.FIELDID = 195
--            )
            ;

SPOOL OFF;


